# Simplifying Rust matching with combinators

Tags: error-handling, rust, pattern-matching

I have something like this:

```
match fnX(
    fnY(x), // Returns Result<(), X>
) // Returns Result<(), Y>
.await
{
    Ok(v) => {
        if v.is_err() {
            error!("error = {}", v);
        }
    }
    Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
};
```

How can I write this with combinators so that I only have to `error!` once? I don't want to do anything with the `Ok` value, just print the error whether it comes from `fnX` or `fnY`.

Comment: The expectations are really unclear, how could you have a `v.is_err()` from a function which returns a `Result<(), Y>`? That makes no sense, by definition `v` is going to be `()` which doesn't have an `is_err`. And does `fnX()` really take a `Result<(), X>` as input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant to simplify something like this (removing the `.await` that is unrelated to the issue):

```
match fnX(x) { // Returns Result<X, EX>
    Ok(y) => match fnY(y) { // Returns Result<Y, EY>
        Ok(_) => println!("Success!"),
        Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
    },
    Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
}
```

If the error types are the same, you can simplify the code with [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then):

```
match fnX(x).and_then(fnY) {
    Ok(_) => println!("Success!"),
    Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
}
```

If the error types are different, you can use [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) to convert them to a single type:

```
match fnX(x)
    .map_err(MyError::from)
    .and_then(|y| fnY(y).map_err(MyError::from))
{
    Ok(_) => println!("Success!"),
    Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
}
```

The latter can be simplified using the latest development version of the [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) crate:

```
match map_for!(y <- fnX (x);
               v <- fnY (y);
               => v)
{
    Ok(_) => println!("Success"),
    Err(e @ MyError { .. }) => error!("error = {}", e),
}
```

- Note that the `@ MyError {..}` annotation is only required if the compiler is unable to infer the error type automatically.
- Full disclaimer: I am the author of the `map_for` crate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need such a "combinator".

`fnX` accepts an argument of type `Result<(), X>` and returns a `Result<(), Y>`

When the code is convoluted it may help to separate the expressions, making it more readable.

```
let result = fnY(x);
match fnX(result).await {
    Ok(v) => {
        // here v is ok value, in this case ()
    }
    Err(e) => error!("error = {}", e),
};
```